# Parse and format the date from the GitHub API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-api

The current value that is returned from a [GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/) request looks like this:

`2013-09-12T22:42:02Z`

How do I parse this value and make it look nicer?

Comment: @Blender I saw that one, but the problem is the recommended code (in the second answer) throws a _ValueError: unconverted data remains: Z_. I posted the proper answer in case anyone else attempts the same thing as I.

Comment: Not the accepted answer. The second answer will, as it doesn't actually parse the date format properly.

Comment: @Blender I skipped the accepted answer since it's easier not to have to install modules, but rather use the ones at hand. I preferred just adjusting the `strptime` formatting to fit the GitHub API.

Comment: Plus the name of this question/answer helps Googlers find a solution if they don't know the name of the date/time standard specifically used by the API.

Comment: Right, but the returned format is ISO 8601. Parsing it with `datetime.strptime` only handles one specific case of ISO 8601.

Comment: Just a head's up: [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) will parse these into datetime objects for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The date format returned from the GitHub API is in the ISO 8601 format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`

To convert that string into a Python date object, use the module `datetime`:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(<date_string>, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

You can then parse this string to the format of your choosing using `date.strftime()`:

```
# Result: Thursday Sep 12, 2013 at 22:42 GMT
date.strftime('%A %b %d, %Y at %H:%M GMT')
```

Or if you want it to be more "automatic", the directive `%c` will automatically choose a date/time string based on your system's locale and language settings.

```
# On my system, I get the following output:
#  Thu Sep 12 22:42:02 2013
date.strftime('%c')
```

If you want to customize it, a full list of directives can be found here: http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior